# Number of rows that are using the foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with counting the number of items/rows that are using the foreign key.

For example.

Table "A" has a foreign key of "group_id" and there is a row with "group_id" of "5" and a couple of items/posts/rows in table "B" are using the foreign key (in this case the ID of "5"). How would I know how to cont the rows that are using that "group_id"?

Here's what I mean.

[image: reference]

Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**

Here is a sketch that explains my problem

PK = Primary Key

FK = Foreign key

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What results do you want?

Comment: So both table "A" and "B" have a `group_id` column, and you want to know how many total records in tables "A" and "B" have `group_id = 5`?

Comment: Not really @kmoser See the sketch.

Comment: @Jwan "5" <> "6" so add some text which explains what you really want to do. In the bottom table, the third column will have value "5" if it has a foreign key to the upper table (with the black lines)

Comment: Sorry forgot to change it :)

Comment: It does not become clear why the answer from Bill is "Not really. See the sketch." ...

Comment: Because I did it wrong. Now all works out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the number of rows like this:

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(*) FROM table_B GROUP BY group_id;
```

Your image seems to show that you want table_A to keep the count persistently as an attribute column.

Some people design triggers for this. For example, in an INSERT trigger on table_B, increment the count attribute column of table_A by 1. In a DELETE trigger on table_B, decrement the count column of table_A by 1.

This sort of works, but it causes more overhead for inserts and deletes, and it causes more exclusive locking on table_A.

It's easier to do the SELECT query that I showed above.